# How come my bind for ctrl-` doesn't work in Sublime Text 2 on Bootcamp?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook-pro, boot-camp, sublime-text-2

Not sure what's up with this. But my default bind for ctrl-` in Sublime Text 2 doesn't work. I can rebind it to something else, that works, but the app doesn't recognize any bind involving the ` key.

I'm on a late 2011 15" MacBook Pro and running Windows 7 via Bootcamp.

One of the problems appears to be, after logging input, that when I hold the control button, Sublime Text believes that the input that was pressed was \.

If I hold the Fn key, I can actually convince it that yes, it is a backquote. But once I started looking at this, I found all kinds of other weird little issues.

Language is set to United States English, and the keyboard is set to United States (Apple).

Any ideas?

Comment: So it turns out that the United States (Apple) keyboard was the culprit. I set standard US keyboard to default and everything works now, and there's no apparent downside.

Comment: In two hours, you can **answer your own question** — please do that as soon as you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The United States (Apple) keyboard is the culprit. Setting the keyboard to standard US keyboard as default fixes the issue, with no apparent downside.